# Keep track of time point was put in array

Tags: java, time, arraylist, point

What is the best way to keep track of the time a point was put in an arraylist so that they are removed when they expire?

```
ArrayList<Point> path=new ArrayList<Point>();
path.add(new Point( 1, 1)// time=1
path.add(new Point( 2,2)// time=2
path.add(new Point(3,3) //time=3
```

so if time becomes 4 any points that were put in before then are expired and can be removed

Comment: Don't you mean `path.add(new Point(1,1));`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `Point` object and a `time` field in another object. Could be called something like `PointWithTime`..etc.

Then add those to your `ArrayList` instead of `Point` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having an `ArrayList<Point>`, consider a `LinkedList<PointAndTime>`. A `LinkedList` will be more efficient to remove items from the start, and you need to store both the point *and* the time, so combine them in the same type.

Comment: Wouldn't an ArrayDeque be more efficient than both of them?